# How to plot a graph for correlation co-efficient between each attributes of a dataset and target attribute using Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am new to Python and I need to plot a graph between correlation coefficient of each attributes against target value. I have an input dataset with huge number of values. I have provided sample dataset value as below. We need to predict whether a particular consumer will leave or not in a company and hence Result column is the target variable.

```
SALARY  DUE RENT    CALLSPERDAY CALL DURATION   RESULT
238790  7   109354  0                     6     YES
56004   0   204611  28                    15    NO
671672  27  371953  0                      4    NO
786035  1   421999  19                    11    YES
89684   2   503335  25                     8    NO
904285  3   522554  0                     13    YES
12072   4   307649  4                     11    NO
23621   19  389157  0                      4    YES
34769   11  291214  1                      13   YES
945835  23  515777  0                      5    NO
```

Here, if you see, the result column is String where as rest of the columns are integer. Similar to result, I also have few other columns(not mentioned in sample) which have string value. Here, I need to compute the values of column which has both string and integer values. 
Using dictionary I have assigned a value to each of the columns which has string value. 
Example: Result column has Yes or No. Hence assigned value as below:

```
D = {'NO': 0, 'YES': 1}
```

and using lambda function, looped through each columns of dataset and replaced NO with 0 and YES with 1.
I tried to  calculate the correlation coefficient using the formula:

```
pearsonr(S.SALARY,targetVarible)
```

Where S is the dataframe which holds all values.
Similarly, I will loop through all the columns of dataset and calculate correlation coefficient of each columns agains target variable.

Is this an efficient way of calculating correlation coefficient?
Because, I am getting value as below
(0.088327739664096655, 1.1787456108540725e-25)
e^-25 seems to be too small.

Is there any other way to calculate it? Would you be suggesting any other way to input String values, so that it can be treated as integer when compared with other columns that has integer values(other than Dictionaries and lambdas which I used?)

Also I need to plot bar graph using the same code. I am planning to use from matplotlib import pyplot as plt library.

Would you be suggesting any other function to plot bar graph. Mostly Im using sklearn libraries,numpy and pandas to use existing functions from them.
It would be great, if someone helps me. Thanks.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Comment: The above formula computes correlation coefficient only for one column. But I need to compute by comparing 2 columns. For example if I have 10 columns with target attribute at 10th column, I need to compute correlation coefficient for each of the column with 10th column. (Example, 1st column and 10th column, 2nd column and 10th column, 3rd column and 4th column, etc..). I need to iterate through each column using for loop and then compute the result. So my result should be example:

        (0.02,0.2) (1st and 10th Col)
        (0.1,0.003) (2nd and 10th Col)

and it goes on..

Comment: Im using the formula

      df = pd.DataFrame(S)

      for i in range(0,10):
      coeff = pearsonr(df[i:],targetVarible)

But getting below error:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (14000,12) (14000,)

Comment: `df.corr()` will calculate the correlation coefficients for each combination of columns in `df`. It should be fairly efficient. Your error is caused by incorrect slicing of your dataframe. `df[i:]` means take the i-th row onward. You need to use column slicing, e.g., `df.iloc[:,i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, df.iloc[:,i] solved slicing issue. Now, i got the correlation coefficient and variable coeff holds the entire value as below.


(0.015276990957300297, 0.070677809213518031)
(0.088327739664096655, 1.1787456108540725e-25)
(0.23333357248460856, 1.9664988076419354e-172)
(0.063525554286212399, 5.3380874135192959e-14)
(-0.21236759430891403, 1.6844874116837465e-142)
(0.088098200193423654, 1.5724998265739893e-25)

Now I need to plot a bar graph for both these values in coeff. As requested in my original question, Would you recommend any other function to plot the graph?

Comment: As far as histograms go, see matplotlib.pyplot.hist. As for other functions, correlation matrices (as produced by df.corr()) are often visualized using heatmaps. Seaborn has a very simple implementation: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked matplotlib and I was able to get the chart from there.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can use df.corr() to get the correlation matrix of your data. Assuming the name of your DataFrame is df you can plot the correlation with:

```
df_corr = df.corr()
df_corr[['RESULT']].plot(kind='hist')
```

Pandas DataFrames have a plot function that uses matplotlib. You can learn more about it here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html